# Running multiple application instances on different cores Mac Studio M1 Ultra

Tags: automator, cpu

I've been running different Blender instances using the Automator and running the shell command to open up Blender in multiple instances. My issue is the CPU usage does not increase when rendering on multiple instances at once and the rendering is slow. I'm assuming this is because they're all sharing the same cores.

How can I assign separate cores to separate application instances?

Comment: You don't. The OS assigns core usage. Setting affinity to a core like on a PC reduces efficiency. Even on an app with simple single threading, using two or more instances should automatically let the OS split the tasks more efficiently. [I have no citation or reference for this other than experience, so I can't provide an actual answer].

Comment: The issue is that blender does not officially support multiple instances yet so I have to run them through the Automator, I'm guessing this is why it does not automatically let the os split the tasks and they just all end up using the same cores. If you have any idea how I could get around this maybe using processor affinity I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/44002 and https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/107524